# Serialize a selection (html) with javascript

Tags: javascript, webview

How i can serialize a selection (in javascript) of text in webView (html page) and restore this selection after the user reload the application ?

Comment: What do you mean by serializing text?

Comment: @NADH It's not serializing text, it's serializing a selection (meaning the user's highlighted selection).

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [serializer module](http://code.google.com/p/rangy/wiki/SerializerModule) of my [Rangy](http://code.google.com/p/rangy) library. For a similar but more lightweight solution, you could use [this code snippet](http://home.arcor.de/martin.honnen/javascript/storingSelection1.html) by Martin Honnen.

Comment: i have tried to use your rangy in an iOS project bt it's not working ? How about the code of martin Honnen, i have not found it ? thanks

Comment: Not working how? Martin Honnen's code can be found in the HTML source of the page I linked to.

Comment: Ok good, i have seen that he use xpath but my webView is dynamic, i think that this code will not work if the webView change it's content ?

Comment: @iPhoneDev: Yes, that's true. Same is true of the Rangy serializer module. In which case, how do you expect your serialization to work?

Comment: I am developing an iOS application ( witch a book), i have many UIWebView in this application. the user can select a text and i would like to serialize the selection and store it in the server and later restore this selection, but the content of my webView can change.

Answer (score -3):

Use the serialize function in jquery
Demo in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tqGmP/)

Comment: @mikerobi oops! thought jquery would satisfy the needs. Sorry