# JavaScript: save and reload a range

Tags: javascript, text, range

How can I save a range (based on user selection) and reload it the next time the user visit my page again?

Details: the user selects a portion of text and I highlight it with a span. Now I have to save the "coordinates" of the selected text, so the next time the user visits my page, I'll load the range coordinates from my db and highlight the text with a span.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some similar answers:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/10386105/96100
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/3607788/96100

Also (self-promotion alert) you could try [Rangy's highlighter module](http://rangy.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/highlighter.html).

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [Rangy](https://code.google.com/p/rangy/) library. It will do what you want, and more. You can take a look at the [Serializer](https://code.google.com/p/rangy/wiki/SerializerModule) module and also the [Highlighter](https://code.google.com/p/rangy/wiki/HighlighterModule) module (this module is still in alpha, and so it may be unstable).